# Is it possible to share network locations(not just internet) using Wifi? [Corporate Domain]

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, connection-sharing

I use my laptop at work and to be able to connect to the internet whenever needed i bought a USB wifi adaptor which i plugged in my work machine and set to broadcast using the popular
'netsh wlan start hostednetwork'

Everything is working fine but I can't access other machines from my Laptop.
Only 2 PCs visible in my Network are my Laptop and my Work-PC

Is it possible to share more than just the internet using this technique?

Comment: Is your laptop on the work domain?  Does it get an IP address from a DHCP server on the work network?

Comment: No my Laptop is not on the work domain, i guess it gets its IP from my machine.